# Creating arrays and resizing them

Tags: vb.net, arrays, resize, element

Lets say I want to create an array with 20 elements all set to a default value (let's say, 0)

But later, during runtime, I might want to resize the array. I might make it larger, to support 30 elements. The 10 new elements will have the default value of 0.

Or I might want to make my array smaller, to just 5. So I delete the complete the existence of the last 15 elements of the array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReDim Preserve will do it, and if the array were declared at the module level, any code referencing it will not lose the reference. I do believe this is specific to vb, however, and there is also a performance penalty, in that this, too, is creating a copy of the array.

I haven't checked, but I suspect the method user274204 describes above is probably the CLR-compliant way to do this . .

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Initialize your array:
    Dim Integers(20) As Integer

    'Output to the console, and you will see 20 elements of value 0
    Me.OutputArrayValues(Integers)

    'Iterate through each element and assign an integer Value:
    For i = 0 To UBound(Integers)
        Integers(i) = i
    Next

    'Output to console, and you will have values from 0 to 20:
    Me.OutputArrayValues(Integers)

    'Use Redim Preserve to expand the array to 30 elements:
    ReDim Preserve Integers(30)

    'output will show the same 0-20 values in elements 0 thru 20, and then 10 0 value elements:
    Me.OutputArrayValues(Integers)

    'Redim Preserve again to reduce the number of elements without data loss:
    ReDim Preserve Integers(15)

    'Same as above, but elements 16 thru 30 are gone:
    Me.OutputArrayValues(Integers)

    'This will re-initialize the array with only 5 elements, set to 0:
    ReDim Integers(5)
    Me.OutputArrayValues(Integers)


End Sub

Private Sub OutputArrayValues(ByVal SomeArray As Array)
    For Each i As Object In SomeArray
        Console.WriteLine(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What looks like a lot of code is simply a bunch of comments explaining what is happening.

Comment: Note that, for multi-dimensional arrays, this only works for the last dimension. Here's a link with more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to resize an array (or any other object for that matter) once created.

You can use System.Array.Resize(ref T[], int) for a similar effect. However this will actually create a new array with the relevant portions copied across and may not be what you want if there are multiple references to the array scattered around.